# No response on opened port

Tags: networking, vpn, port-forwarding

I successfully installed a VPN script on my server and can see that it was configured to listen on port `54321` which is confirmed by `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEND`.

The VPN is running, I see the port being listened to, but whenever I navigate to <ip_address>:54321 I get nothing besides a timeout.

Is there any further configuration needed on Ubuntu to allow traffic to/from port 54321? I have opened the port in my firewall and technically it should work.

Appreciate any advice, thank you.